# Calculate rank of hash value and insert it into a CSV file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash, ruby-csv

I have one hash

`h1 = {"Cust1"=>500, "Cust4"=>400, "Cust2"=>100, "Cust3"=>100}`

I want to insert this hash into a **CSV** file with the ranking of keys according to their value.

The sample output should look like this

`ID,Sales,Rank Cust1,500,1 Cust4,400,2 Cust2,100,3 Cust3,100,3`

I have to write the program in **Ruby**.

Comment: I suggest that you: 1) state whether `h1`'s key-value pairs are guaranteed to be ordered by decreasing value; 2) clarify that equal values are to have equal ranks (though it is implied by your "sample output"); and 3) display `"ID,Sales,Rank"`, `"Cust1,500,1"`, `"Cust4,400,2"`, `"Cust2,100,3"` and `"Cust3,100,3"` on separate lines if that is what the CSV file is to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each_with_index` method of hash

```
arr = [['ID', 'Sales', 'Rank']]

h1.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|
  arr << [key, value, index + 1]
end

arr #[["ID", "Sales", "Rank"], ["Cust1", 500, 1], ["Cust4", 400, 2], ["Cust2", 100, 3], ["Cust3", 100, 4]]
```

Code for CSV

```
h1 = {"Cust1"=>500, "Cust4"=>400, "Cust2"=>100, "Cust3"=>100}
# You can skip following `sort_by` line if your hash is already ordered by desc value
h1 = h1.sort_by {|_k,v| v}.reverse.to_h
h2 = h1.group_by {|k,v| v }
require 'csv'
CSV.open("myfile.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << ['ID', 'Sales', 'Rank']
  h2.each_with_index do |(key, values), index|
    values.each do |value|
      csv << [value[0], key, index + 1]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: With Index I can achieve this . But I am not able to calculate the Rank . If two of them have same value , then they should have same rank

Comment: @SayandipGhatak:- Check my edited answer, if your hash is sorted according to the `sales` i.e. 500, 400 etc then you can use `h2 = h1.group_by {|k,v| v }` to group by the `sales`

Comment: @CarySwoveland:- Thanks for the comment, I have updated the answer with a comment.

Comment: You don't need `to_h`. If desired you could write `h1.sort_by(&:last).reverse`.

Comment: Actually I wanted `h1` to be` hash` only, without `to_h` it will be `[["Cust1", 500], ["Cust4", 400], ["Cust3", 100], ["Cust2", 100]]`

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks to calculate the rank; since 1.9 Ruby retains the insertion sequence of the hash, and in this instance, hash `h1` is already in the correct order. But if the data came from a REST call or was not already sorted in ranked sequence the solution above would produce incorrect output. To fix this

```rb
require 'csv'

h1 = {"Cust1"=>500, "Cust2"=>100, "Cust4"=>400, "Cust3"=>100}

ranked_customers = h1.sort_by { |k, v| [-v, k] }.each_with_index { |e, i| e.push i + 1 }
ranked_customers.unshift %w[ID Sales Rank]

CSV { |csv_out| ranked_customers.each { |e| csv_out << e } }
```

produces

```
ID,Sales,Rank
Cust1,500,1
Cust4,400,2
Cust2,100,3
Cust3,100,4
```

Cust2 and Cust3 both have the same sales value, but Cust2 sorts ahead of Cust3 alphabetically.

Comment: The OP wants the last line to be `"Cust3,100,3"` because `100` has rank `3`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the key-value pairs of `h1` are not necessarily in order of decreasing values.

We need to make two calculations to construct the CSV file.

```
order = h1.sort_by { |_,v| -v }
  #=> [["Cust1", 500], ["Cust4", 400], ["Cust2", 100], ["Cust3", 100]]
nbr_ranks = order.map(&:last).uniq.size
  #=> 3
```

The file can be constructed as follows.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open('t.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << ['ID', 'Sales', 'Rank']
  last_val = order.first.last
  order.each do |name, val|
    unless val == last_val
      nbr_ranks -= 1
      last_val = val
    end
    csv << [name, val, nbr_ranks]
  end
end
```

```
puts File.read('t.csv')
ID,Sales,Rank
Cust1,500,1
Cust4,400,2
Cust2,100,3
Cust3,100,4
```

---

If the key-value pairs of `h1` are guaranteed to be in order of decreasing values (as in the example), there is no need to compute the array `order`.

```
nbr_ranks = order.map(&:last).uniq.size
  #=> 3

CSV.open('t.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << ['ID', 'Sales', 'Rank']
  last_val = h1[h1.keys.first]
  h1.each do |name, val|
    unless val == last_val
      nbr_ranks -= 1
      last_val = val
    end
    csv << [name, val, nbr_ranks]
  end
end
```

Note:

```
last_val = h1[h1.keys.first]
  #=> 500
```